# When exporting an ipython notebook to html, long output doesn't have a scroll bar

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have an iPython notebook with some very long output cells, which automatically get a scroll bar when editing the live notebook. When I convert to HTML with

`ipython nbconvert myfile.ipynb`

everything looks fine except that the long output cells don't have a scroll bar. If I manually edit the HTML and add the `output_scroll` class to the cells, the scroll bar appears.

Is this the expected behaviour? I thought that nbconvert to HTML was supposed to preserve scroll behaviour.

Comment: did you ever solve this? I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: Still wondering if this has been solved...?

Answer (score 3):

Until now, it still hasn't that ability. I suggest that change manually at

```
 <div class=".."> to 
 <div class=".."style="overflow-y: scroll; height:400px;">
```

Maybe because of it doesn't know which fields long/short

Comment: Yes this works but it is a manual approach. Can this be made from jupyter notebook settings?